# Propositional logic: why is "not A or (not A and B) = not A"

Tags: logic

Can anyone tell me (formal), why

```
not A or (not A and B)
```

is

```
not A?
```

Comment: Because if you NOT both sides you get:

Comment: @mazenelzoor The OP is correct, you are not. `(¬A ∨ (¬A ∧ B))` has the same truth table as `¬A`, it's easy to verify

Comment: Because if you NOT both sides you get: 
**a** = **a** & **a** or !b

Comment: Make C=NOT A, and it becomes C or (C and B). Clearly C has short circuited the or expression

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a logic question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A or (A and B) == A
```

is always a tautology (where A here can be replaced by "not A" or any other boolean expression, similarly for B).

You don't need to consider the whole truth table as the others have done, just consider the values of A itself (i.e., just two cases) and apply the rules of Boolean logic to simplify:

- if A is true, then we have:  `true or (true and B)` which is trivially true (by definition of or - `true or X` is always `true`).
- if A is false, then we have `false or (false and B) == (false and B) == false` (by definition of or (`false or X == X`) and or (`false and X == false`)).

Depending on your personal taste, it might be more intuitive to recall that or relates to UNION in set theory, and "and" relates to INTERSECTION. In this case, clearly. A UNION (A INTERSECTION B) is equal to A, as (A INTERSECTION B) is a strict subset of A.

Comment: okay. the second point is exactly, what I wanted to know. THX everyone for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

```
!A || (!A && B) means :

if(A = true and B = true) => false (!A)

if(A = True and B = false) => false (!A)

if(A = false and B = True) => True (!A)

if(A = false and B = false) => True (!A)
```

in all cases your expression is !A
It is called the truth table of the inputs of an expression.

If you have a large set of inputs and logic operations, this method is not easy to verify your expression.

what you can do in that case :

proof `!A = !A || (!A && B)` the same as proving `A = !(!A || (!A && B))`

```
!(!A || (!A && B)) = A && !(!A && B) = A && (A || !B) = A
```

Comment: This isn't a valid way to do this. In this case you only have a small expression with 4 different outputs. Sometimes expressions can get up to 100 (!) and 100(&&).

Comment: That's why it is called the truth table of an expression! when it is limited to a small number of inputs;

Comment: The OP asked, "Can anyone tell me (*formal*), **why**". The OP already knew they were the same, so your answer doesn't add to that knowledge; you don't explain **why**. Frankly, I don't think that this is a programming question and the OP should ask this on a mathematics side. But this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I agree with you, I've updated my answer for both cases ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following is the proof:

```
A B     A and B(AND gate)     A or (A and B) OR gate     
0 0            0                        0                      
0 1            0                        0
1 0            0                        1
1 1            1                        1
```

You can see the value of A is same as the output of A or (A and B) OR gate.